# Code signing certificates created with match don't show up in XCode 10.3

Tags: ios, code-signing, fastlane, code-signing-certificate, fastlane-match

Since updating my profiles and certificates with fastlane match I can't select any of the installed signing certificates in XCode 10.3 when exporting after archiving the app. The certificate shows up in the 'General' and 'Build Settings' tab of XCode however.

Match was run on my machine successfully and the new certificate shows up in my keychain as valid. I suspect this is due to the renaming of the certificates. The old ones were called 'iPhone Distribution: xxx (xxx)", the new ones are "Apple Distribution: xxx (xxx)". If I ask XCode to recreate a certificate it will be named 'iPhone Distribution..." as well.

Any ideas if this is in fact the reason?